# Azure ServiceFabric Stateful Service, not accessible after configuration in portal

Tags: c#, azure, dns, azure-service-fabric

- Created a Basic Azure Service Fabric , Stateful Service, using      reliable service framework using .NET core.
- Created a values controller with get operation returning string collection
- created endpoint configuration in service manifest with protocol of http
- Created DNS service name in the application manifest for the service
- Created Azure service fabric Cluster from portal
- Configured the nodes with ReverseProxy and Enable DNS
- Configured the LB rules 8081,80,19080,19000
- Have healthprobe at 19000,19080,8081
- Published my azure fabric application from Visual studio, and I can open the fabric explorer, it shows my services are deployed correctly
- but not able to access the service from outside of cluster

> http://domain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/MyCalculatorApplication/AgeCalculatorService/api/values  throws exception as {"Error":{"Code":"E_INVALIDARG","Message":"Invalid argument"}}

Comment: According to you mentioned execution it seems that you don't supply the valid argument.It seems that there is no relationship with accessible.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to use the naming service of service fabric, first you should resolve the endpoint using this url:

```
http://domain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Services/MyCalculatorApplication/AgeCalculatorService/$/ResolvePartition?api-version=3.0&PartitionKeyType=1&timeout=60
```

Then you can use one of the endpoints

Comment: It seems like that the name "http://domain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com" is not valid anymore. What the response that you've got?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the correct endpoint.
Your url should be something like this:
http://domain.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com:**SERVICEPORT**/api/values